# Ember Data Firebase rules confusion

Tags: ember.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, emberfire

I'm getting started with my first Ember/Firebase application and having trouble finding documentation that goes beyond public data.

My goal is to have an application where signed in users can create and view their own data. I see that Firebase suggests this rule for such a situation:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't find out any information about how this would work on the Ember end. For example, assuming I have an "entry" model that I am saving:

```
save(model) {
  model.save().then( () => {
    this.transitionToRoute('index');
  }, error => {
    console.error(`error: ${error}`);
  })
},
```

Not sure if I need to be storing a uid in the model?

And then if I want the user to get a listing of their own entries:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('entry');
  }
});
```

This produces the following error:

> ember.debug.js:30610 Error while processing route: index permission_denied at /entries: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. Error: permission_denied at /entries: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

At this point I'm not sure what I should be doing –– do I need to build a custom URL or add a namespace in my firebase adapter to add a users/xxx prefix? Or etc?

Cannot find any documentation/tutorials/walkthroughs that cover anything beyond public read/write data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this work eventually. It basically boiled down to storing the uid from Firebase auth in a service after login (I added [ember-local-storage](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-local-storage) in case of page refresh), and then adding a pathForType method to the application adapter to nest all users data under users/${uid}, so in firebase data is ending up in this configuration: users/${uid}/entries/${entry_id}.

### application/adapter.js

```
import FirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/adapters/firebase';
import Ember from 'ember';
export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({

    /* inject service to access uid */
  journalist: Ember.inject.service('journalist'),

    /* path for type nests /entries under users/${uid} */
    pathForType(type) {
      let uid =  this.get('journalist.uid');
      let path = Ember.String.pluralize(type);
    return  `users/${uid}/${path}`;
   }

});
```

### application/route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    /* injecting service to set uid */
  journalist: Ember.inject.service('journalist'),

  beforeModel() {
    return this.get('session').fetch().catch();
  },
  actions: {
    signIn(provider) {
      this.get('session').open('firebase', {provider: provider}).then(data => {

        /* setting uid in service for later retrieval elsewhere */
        this.get('journalist').setUID(data.uid);
        this.transitionTo('entries');
    });
    },
    signOut() {
      this.get('session').close().then(() => this.transitionTo('application'));

    }
  }
});
```

### entries/route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    /* nothing special required for ember data save, findAll, etc, adapter takes care of everything */
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('entry');
    }
});
```

### services/journalist.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { storageFor } from 'ember-local-storage';
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    uid: null,
    localStore: storageFor('journalist-session'),
    init() {
        const localStore = this.get('localStore');
    this.set('uid', localStore.get('uid'));
  },
    setUID(id) {
        this.set('uid', id);
        this.set('localStore.uid', id);
    }
});
```

### storages/journalist-session:

```
import StorageObject from 'ember-local-storage/local/object';
const Storage = StorageObject.extend();
 Storage.reopenClass({
   initialState() {
     return {
       uid: null
     };
   }
 });
export default Storage;
```

### firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be happy with feedback if you have any ideas on anything that looks awry in this code – in terms of the necessity of the service for uid, or firebase rules, etc.